Pod Files are still red/missing even reinstalling pod
I tried to rename the project (eg from “A B C” to “ABC” no space) but I messed it up badly by using global cmmd F to just rename things. Now the pod files are all messed up.
Most posts advise a pod reinstatement (pod deintegrate, pod clean cache —all, pod install).  I tried it, but:

While it restored some missing files, not all.  Screen cap 1 below shows the ones that are still missing.
The Xcode project in the file navigator seems to have duplicated itself.

Screen cap 1 shows the missing files on the navigator
Not sure if the following is related. When I try to run the project, it warns “/Users/[name]/Documents/[project name in Finder]/[new project name now in Xcode file navigator].xcodeproj One of the paths in DEVELOPMENT_ASSET_PATHS does not exist: /Users/[name]/Documents/[project name in Finder]/[old file name with space]/Preview Content”
Screen cap 2 shows the run/build error. .
Any advice help. Thank you!
